# How to Delete MSSQL Table Rows if they are Older than One Year/One Day

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, days, getdate

I am trying to create a PHP query to delete SQL table rows if the `order_date` column is a over a year old. I would also like a second query where table rows will be deleted if the same column is a day old.

To go more in depth, the `order_date` column is in my current table, `tracking_orders`, and was created using part of a query: `order_date datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),`. The `tracking_orders` table currently looks like this:

```
order_date  tracking_order  account_id
Apr 7 2014 3:49PM   1   1
Apr 7 2014 3:51PM   2   1
```

The day I am asking this question is April 8th 2014, so I am trying to make a query to delete rows if the `order_date` data is Apr 7 2013, and another query to delete rows if the
`order_date` data is Apr 7 2014. Also, if the data is more than 1 year old, I would still like it to delete. For example, Apr 7 2012.

For a code example, I am looking for something like this:

```
$sql = 'DELETE * from tracking_orders WHERE order_date == DATE_SUB(getdate(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)';
```

And something like this, to delete after one day:

```
$sql = 'DELETE * from tracking_orders WHERE order_date == DATE_SUB(getdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)';
```

Note: the above doesn't work because `DATE_SUB` is MySQL syntax, and I am working with MSSQL.

Thank you for any help. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing it'll be similar but using the `DATEADD` method, [see this Microsoft Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Comment: That was me that +1'd you before. :) Here's another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE from tracking_orders 
WHERE DATEDIFF(dy,order_date, getdate()) = 1 
OR DATEDIFF(yy,order_date, getdate()) > 1
```

The first condition in where checks for a difference of 1 day, and the second for a difference greater than 1 year. Note that this is going strictly by the calendar so the below will also return 1 even though time difference is less than 24 hours:

```
select datediff (dy, '2013-01-01 23:00:00.000', '2013-01-02 22:00:00.000')
```

To check for 24 hour difference only use `DATEDIFF(hh,order_date, getdate()) = 1`

Comment: I am using `$sql = 'DELETE * from tracking_orders 
WHERE DATEDIFF(dy,order_date, getdate()) = 1';` and I am getting the error ` Incorrect syntax near '*'. (severity 15)`.

Comment: Nice, thank you. So if one of my rows order_date data was June 10 2013, and I used the query `$sql = 'DELETE * from tracking_orders  WHERE DATEDIFF(yy,order_date, getdate()) > 1';` then would it not be deleted when running the query?

Comment: No, because we explicitly check that difference in the year part is greater than 1.